# How to deduce the type of template argument based on some conditions and return information about that type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, variant

Suppose I have a class `C` that has holds a `std::variant<A, B>`. The constructor of `C` must be a templated constructor that can accept any type, and based on that type it must initialize the variant in different ways.

Here is a simplified overview:

```
struct A {
    // ...
};

struct B {
    // ...
};

class C {
    public:
        template <typename T>
        C(T arg) {
            if constexpr (std::same_v<B, T>) {
                var = B{arg};
            }
            else if constexpr (std::is_constructible<A, T>) {
                var = A{arg};
            }
        }

    private:
        std::variant<A, B> var;
};
```

I am looking for a way to squash these if constexpr statements by using some template metaprogramming magic, so I may rewrite the constructor like this (hoping to avoid the extra initialization of the variant):

```
template<T>
struct DeduceAOrB {
  // ..... somehow check the conditions here 
};

template <typename T>
        C(T arg)
            : var(DeduceAOrB<T>::type{arg})
        {}
```

Important note is that the variant may need to be expanded in the future, so the solution must be viable for arbitrarily many types

Comment: Just put those `if conextexpr`s in a helper function and then use `template <typename T> C(T arg) : var(helper_function_name(arg)) {}`

Comment: I think you just need to overload it `C(B arg){var = arg;}`

Comment: fwiw, you can also sfinae check `std::is_constructible` without `if constexpr`

Comment: @NathanOliver But what would be the return type of the helper function? The functions return type in your case must be the same for every ```if constexpr``` branch, but that is clearly not the case, as it can be either ```A``` or ```B```

Comment: @TheMemeMachine You use `auto`: `template <typename T> auto helper(T arg) { ... }`

Comment: @appleapple I would like to avoid making many different constructor overloads, I am seeking a cleaner approach. Regarding your second comment, I am not sure what you mean, how would i use ```is_constructuble``` without an if statement?

Comment: @TheMemeMachine but template instantiate are still different functions, I see no reason avoid overload here. (and imo squeeze all the code inside giant `if constexpr` are pretty not clean)

Comment: @NathanOliver hmm, that approach works, but only in the case where the the if statements are all constexpr. In the case where the conditions are not constexpr, that will fail compilation. Any suggestions for that case?

Comment: @TheMemeMachine If you have cases that aren't constexpr, then nothing is going to help.  Even doing something like `DeduceAOrB<T>::type` can't work with with things that are not known at compile time.

Comment: @NathanOliver Btw a non-static member function will also work in this case. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3P1zd9a1K).

Comment: @Jason It does, never said it wouldn't.  I suggested a static function as those are easier to work with.  You can give it out as a plain function pointer and that means it needs less overhead if you want to wrap it in some sort of factory function.

Comment: Why would you even bother with TMP if you know the arguments you pass and what object would be instantiated? Why not just simply use a move constructor and create an object T outside of the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to create a helper function containing the conditions and use it in initializer list as shown below:

```
class C {
    private:
        //helper function checking for different conditions and returning based on result
        template<typename T>
        static constexpr auto helperFunc(T arg)
        {
            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<B, T>) {
                        return B{arg};
            }
            else if constexpr (std::is_constructible_v<A, T>) {
                        return A{arg};
            } else {
                        return A{};
            }
        }
    public:
        template <typename T>
//----------------VVV------------------>use helperFunc initializer list
        C(T arg): var(helperFunc(arg)){
            
            
        }

    private:
        std::variant<A, B> var;
};
```

Comment: Great idea, however what would I do in case the if conditions are not constexpr? In that case, the auto return type will complain during compilation

Comment: @TheMemeMachine You can/should ask a new separate question for those follow up question. One question per post is recommended.

Comment: @TheMemeMachine In the new separate question, you can perhaps provide a link to this question and show the code and also that you have the solution when the conditions are constexpr and that you now want to know for the case when the condition are not constexpr. Also I would recommend playing with the code and also reading about this technique before asking a new question so that you can write a better question.

Comment: @TheMemeMachine This answer seems to answer your question perfectly. Using runtime values is a different thing, but you could have a similar approach. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/oPEnKcMfa)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see, so you added an else branch. I saw your now deleted comment(i think) but was unable to reply at that time.

Comment: @Jason Yeah, I noticed that it would have UB instead of placing a default constructed `A` in the `variant<A,B>` as it does in OPs original. I didn't think about it until I added my own answer to the question using `std::conditional`, which sort of forced the issue :-)

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a way to squash these if constexpr statements by using some template metaprogramming magic

[`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) was created for cases like this. It's `type` will be one of two supplied types depending on the supplied condition:

```cpp
std::conditional_t<boolean,
                   true-type,
                   false-type>
```

and you can of course nest them with as many conditions as you'd like, which will be needed in this case:

```cpp
std::conditional_t<boolean1,
                   true-type1,
std::conditional_t<boolean2,
                   true-type2,
                   false-type>>
```

`DeduceAOrB` could therefore be defined as such:

```cpp
template<class T>
using DeduceAOrB = 
std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<B, std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>,
    B,
std::conditional_t<std::is_constructible_v<A, T>,
    A,
    defaulter<A>>>;
```

Your current constructor using `if constexpr` could then be rewritten like so:

```cpp
template <class T>
C(T&& arg) : var{DeduceAOrB<T>{std::forward<T>(arg)}} {}
```

It uses the exact same logic as you use in your constructor:

- if `std::is_same_v<B, T>` - construct a `B` from `arg`, else
- if `std::is_constructible_v<A, T>` - construct an `A` from `arg`, else
- default construct an `A`

---

The `defaulter` class template is used to create a type that can be constructed from any arguments and is implicitly convertible to `T`, which is used to default construct an `A` in case both conditions fails.

```cpp
template <class T>
struct defaulter {
    template <class... Args> defaulter(Args&&...) {}
    operator T() const { return T{}; }
};
```

[Full demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ee7vbKahn)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one time thing, you can use [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) as shown below. Otherwise you can create a helper function.

```
class C {
    public:
        template <typename T>
//--------------v-------------------->use constructor initializer list
        C(T arg): var([&](){
            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<B, T>) {
                return B{arg};
            }
            else if constexpr (std::is_constructible_v<A, T>) {
                return A{arg};
            }}()) {
            
        }

    private:
        std::variant<A, B> var;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a candidate for `std::type_identity` as a wrapper for types:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct DeduceAOrB : decltype([]
    {
        if constexpr (std::same_v<B, T>) {
            return std::type_identity<B>();
        } else if constexpr (std::is_constructible<A, T>) {
            return std::type_identity<A>();
        }
    }()) {
    // 'type' alias inherited from 'std::type_identity' base class
};
```

You can even inline this decision, should you want to:

```
class C {
    public:
        template <typename T>
        C(T arg) : var(typename decltype([&]
        {
            if constexpr (std::same_v<B, T>) {
                return std::type_identity<B>();
            } else if constexpr (std::is_constructible<A, T>) {
                return std::type_identity<A>();
            }
        }())::type{arg}) {
        }

    private:
        std::variant<A, B> var;
};
```

Comment: Huh, C++17 doesn't allow lambdas in unevaluated context? Well, it's easy enough to translate to a function object class.

Comment: I realized one problem with this approach when I wrote an answer myself just now. If both conditions are `false`, OPs constructor leaves the `variant` with a default constructed `A`.