# Concept to define type A to be equal to type B, if B exists

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, sfinae, c++-concepts

I want `TagOrInt<T>` to be equal to `T::Tag` if `T` has a member type `Tag`, and equal to `int` otherwise. Like:

```
template <class T> using TagOrint = typename T::Tag; // if this is valid
template <class T> using TagOrInt = int;             // otherwise
```

I can do this using SFINAE and a helper struct:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class T, class = void>
struct TagOrIntHelper {
  using type = int;
};
template<class T>
struct TagOrIntHelper<T, std::void_t<typename T::Tag> > {
  using type = T::Tag;
};
template<class T>
using TagOrInt = TagOrIntHelper<T>::type;

// Test case
struct X { using Tag = float; };
struct Y { };
static_assert(std::is_same_v<TagOrInt<X>, float>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<TagOrInt<Y>, int>);
```

This works, but is there a way to do it without SFINAE and a helper struct? I feel that there should be a C++20 way that uses concepts. Or is there an even a simpler way in C++17?

This was my attempt with concepts, but it does not work:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class T>
concept HasTag = requires { (typename T::Tag *)nullptr; };
template<class T>
using TagOrInt = std::conditional_t<HasTag<T>, typename T::Tag, int>;

// Test case
struct Y { };
static_assert(std::is_same_v<TagOrInt<Y>, int>);
```

The instantiation of `Tag_or_int<Y>` fails to compile:

```
concept.cc:5:7: error: no type named ‘Tag’ in ‘struct Y’
```

So apparently `std::conditional_t` requires that both branches compile.

(It was suggested that this question is a duplicate of [How to deduce the type of template argument based on some conditions and return information about that type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383951/how-to-deduce-the-type-of-template-argument-based-on-some-conditions-and-return) . However, the two questions are unrelated:

- This question regards how to **define a type** to an expression that depends on a template argument, if that expression is valid in a particular instantiation, and to some other "default" type otherwise. Further, I want to achieve this using concepts rather than the known SFINAE solution.
- That question regards how to **initialize a member variable** to a value that is computed using a type-dependent algorithm.
  The answers given there are not answers to the question here, and vice versa. So I would like to request that this question is re-opened, especially since both the answers here are interesting and instructive. Thank you!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```cpp
template <class T>
using TagOrint = decltype([]{
    if constexpr (requires { typename T::Tag; }) {
        return std::type_identity<typename T::Tag>();
    } else {
        return std::type_identity<T>();
    }
}())::type;
```

Basically - the lambda gives you a place where you can `if constexpr` on that constraint. But the lambda can't return a *type*, it can only return a value - so we instead return some kind of `std::type_identity<T>`. And then we need to `decltype(...)::type` to actually pull the `T` out.

Answer (score 1):

Here we do SFINAE based testing of a set of traits:

```
template<class T, class=void, template<class...>class... Zs>
struct first_valid {};

template<class T, template<class...>class Z, template<class...>class... Zs>
struct first_valid<T, std::void_t<Z<T>>, Z, Zs...>
{
  using type=Z<T>;
};
template<class T, class V, template<class...>class Z, template<class...>class... Zs>
struct first_valid<T, V, Z, Zs...>:first_valid<T,V, Zs...>{};

template<class T, template<class...>class... Zs>
using first_valid_t = typename first_valid<T, void, Zs...>::type;
```

now we can:

```
template <class T> using TagOrint = typename T::Tag; // if this is valid
template <class T> using TagOrInt = int;    

struct Bob {
  using Tag = Bob;
};

template<class T>
using test = first_valid_t<T, TagOrint, TagOrInt>;

int main() {
  test<Bob> b = Bob{};
  test<double> d = 7;
}
```

`first_valid_t<T, templates...>` finds the first valid template to apply and returns that type.

Comment: Thank you! While this is not literally speaking an answer to my question, since it uses SFINAE, it is very instructive and helpful for what I wanted to achieve.

This does use a helper struct with SFINAE. Is there a way to implement this solution (to a more general problem than the one originally asked) without using SFINAE, and perhaps using concepts instead?

Comment: @SvenSandberg Strictly, SFINAE is a function overload, and I don't overload functions; so I can't be using the sentence in the standard that says "substitution failure is not an error" (ie, SFINAE).  I'm aware that isn't what most people mean when they say SFINAE, but.... what exactly do **you** mean by SFINAE?  Feel-wise, all ways of detecting "is `T::Tag` invalid code" are doing some `T::Tag` substitution and not generating a hard error, but a soft one you can detect, by definition of what you are asking to happen.